# java - understanding a piece of code in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

why i need to write:

```
mat.length-1
```

in the second for loop (the loop it all conditions).

the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length-1; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                j++;
                if (i == mat.length - 1 && j == mat.length - 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i != j && mat[i][j] == mat[j][i]) {
                flag = true;

            } else {
                flag = false;
                if (flag == false) {
                    stop = 1;
                    i = mat.length - 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[Checking program applies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiShm.jpg)

Complete code:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //int[][] mat = { { 9, 2, 4 }, { 2, 9, 7 }, { 4, 7, 9 } };
    int[][]mat = {  { 9, 2, 3, 4},
                    { 2, 9, 6, 3}, 
                    { 3, 6, 9 ,2},
                    { 4, 3, 2 ,9}};

    boolean flag = true;
    int stop = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("[" + mat[i][j] + "]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length-1; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                j++;
                if (i == mat.length - 1 && j == mat.length - 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i != j && mat[i][j] == mat[j][i]) {
                flag = true;

            } else {
                flag = false;
                if (flag == false) {
                    stop = 1;
                    i = mat.length - 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if (stop == 1) {
        System.out.println("Not first folded matrix");
    } else {
        System.out.println("First folded matrix");
    }

}
}
```

this is work but if i change it to

```
mat.length
```

It does not work
If I write a negative one then it stops the loop of the i before it reaches the end of the array.
Can explanation?

Comment: You probably need to code ` for (int i = 0; i < mat.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length-1; j++) {`
as ` for (int i = 0; i < mat.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length-1; j++) {`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, these lines serve no purpose as i and j would never be equal to (mat.length-1) in your code.

```
if (i == mat.length - 1 && j == mat.length - 1) {
    break;
}
```

Change your code to :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < mat.length; j++) {
            if (mat[i][j] != mat[j][i]) {
                flag = false;
                j = mat.length;
                i = mat.length;
            }
        }
    }

    if (flag == false) {
        System.out.println("Not first folded matrix");
    } else {
        System.out.println("First folded matrix");
    }
```